# Can flask (using jinja2) render templates using 'windows-1251' encoding?

Tags: python, crystal-reports, flask, jinja2

I write a simple frontend for pretty old reporting system, which uses Crystal Reports 8 Web Component Server.
And I need to make a 'POST' request to this Web Component. When I'm making request from page encoded using standard UTF-8, all form data is passed in UTF-8 too. And that's the problem, because CR8 Web Component Server doesn't understand UTF-8 (or does it and I'm wrong?).
I've tried to put `accept-charset="ISO-8859-5"` and `accept-charset="windows-1251"` in  parameters and had no luck with it.

Here's more info, that can be usefull:

- This frontend will be working on Windows Server 2003 with IIS6,
- Only suitable browser is IE, because CR8 Web Component Server uses ActiveX component. (There's also a java plugin, but for some reason it doesn't work at all).

So I need flask (jinja2) to render templates using 'windows-1251' encoding, because parameter names and values can contain cyrillic characters. It there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a simple (and maybe even stupid) solution. 
Instead of `return render_template('template.html', params**)`, I'm creating request manually and setting request data and headers to what i need.

And it looks like that:

```
r = Response()
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'
    r.data = render_template('template.html', param1 = data).encode('cp1251')
```

Looks like a dirty hack, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flask, have you read this:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/unicode/

Answer (score 0):

In my case loaders.py had a hardcode "utf-8" in several places which I replaced with "windows-1251" and for me everything worked!